# Is $\sigma$-algebra of iid random variables is the same as the $\sigma$-algebra of an arbitrary of them?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$ be iid random variables. Is it true that $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=\sigma(X_i)$, for any $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$?

I'm asking this to understand if we have a filtration $\mathcal{F}_k=\sigma(\Delta W_1,\Delta W_2,...,\Delta W_k)$ where $\Delta W_i=W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1})$, $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion, and $t_i$'s are all equally spaced, then is it true $\mathcal{F}_k=\sigma(\Delta W_i)$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,k\}$? Intiutively, it feels like it shouldn't be but I cannot see why in mathematical terms.

Comment: No, not at all. $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is much larger than $\sigma(X_i)$.

Comment: @saz but $X_1^{-1}(A) = X_i^{-1}(A)$ for any borel set $A$ and any $i$

Comment: @Jakobian No, why should this be true...?

Comment: @Jakobian Having the same distribution means $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}_i(A)) = \mathbb{P}(X_1^{-1}(A))$. This does **not** imply $X^{-1}_i(A) = X_1^{-1}(A)$.  Just consider e.g. $\Omega := [0,1]$ endowed with Lebesgue measure and the random variables $X_1 :=1_{\{0\}}$ and $X_2 := 1_{\{1\}}$. The random variables have the same distribution but $X^{-1}_1(\{0\}) \neq X_2^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @saz, how can I prove $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ is larger than $\sigma(X_i)$?

Comment: For the random variables which i defined in my previous comment, it holds that $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ is strictly larger than $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no (unless these random variables are degenerate).

Indeed, if these random variables are non-degenerate, then there exists some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X_1\le c)\in(0,1)$ and $P(X_1> c)\in(0,1)$. Consider now the set:
$$
S:=\{X_2\le c\}.
$$

Clearly, $S\in\sigma(X_1,X_2)$, $S\neq\emptyset$, $S\neq \Omega$. Let us check that $S\notin \sigma(X_1)$.

Let us recall that $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$ are independent (this can be checked via the monotone class theorem). Then, if $S\in \sigma(X_1)$ then $S$ would be independent of itself (since clearly $S\in\sigma(X_2)$) and
$$
P(S)=P(S\cap S)=P(S)P(S).
$$
This is possible only if $P(S)$ is $0$ or $1$. Since by above $P(S)\in(0,1)$, we come to the contradiction. Therefore $S\notin \sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_1)\neq\sigma(X_1,X_2)$.